# junit test method for getters & setters

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, getter-setter

I have many java beans in my project. I need to generate a JUnit Test class for them. The test methods generated using Eclipse 3.2 & junit 4.4 look like the following:

```
public void testGetName() {
        // fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetName() {
        // fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetEmployeeid() {
        // fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetEmployeeid() {
        // fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
```

some of my beans have more than 100 fields...

Is there a way by which I can get a single test method for both the getters & setters like  `testEmployeeid()`, `testName()` so that in these methods I can test both my setters & getters rather than using 2 diff. test methods for them...

How should I configure eclipse to do this?

Comment: what eclipse plug-in are you using to generate the test methods?

Comment: FWIW, the following question tries to set aside the debate and ask if there is a way to do it automatically per your preference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108692

Comment: The **real** problem here is totally unrelated to unit testing altogether: "*some of my beans r having more then 100 fields*"... for any Java newbies reading this question, please understand this is *terrible* programming. Any class that has 100+ fields has way too much responsibility. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683841/what-is-object-decomposition) if you don't understand why.

Answer (score 24):

The philosophy of Test Driven Development says "test everything which can possibly break". That is, focus your efforts on the useful tests, instead of writing tests for just the sake of it.

Getters and setters are almost always trivial code, which is not worth testing by themselves.

I know this is not a straight answer to your plea, but I thought it may still help to point this out ;-) So why do you actually need to write tests for all those getters and setters in the first place?

Comment: +1 I agree that accessor methods don't need testing. I'm missing a feature that would allow them to be declared by an annotation.

Comment: I disagree strongly. You test the setters and getters for *regression* purposes, such that when your setters/getters change to be more complex, the tests confirm that they still function as before.

Comment: Yeah, would be nice. Java is too verbose on occasions. C# got this one better.

Comment: Checkout <a href="http://projectlombok.org/" Project Lombok</a> for annotation based approach, or switch to something like Groovy.
Groovy is sort of Java++, but also adds dynamic programming. You don't have to use it, but it's there.
Can rename a .java to .groovy, and groovyc is happy. Then, can use features want from there.

Comment: @Brian: IMO your case is fully covered by the above maxim. If there is a big enough chance that my getter/setter implementation may get more complex in the foreseeable future, then I write my little tests of course. However, I would say that your "when" still looks like a rather a big "if" to me ;-)

Comment: I agree with @Brian. Yes it is true that most Getters and Setters are trivial, which makes testing them trivial. However aside from the regression testing point that @Brian made, testing them can also ensure that things are getting set properly by constructors to. Or if someone extends your class and *doesn't* set something properly. I've argued this with other poeple numerous times, but they are always extremely easy to implement, easier than arguing about it sometimes, especially on the off chance that it does save you time later on.

Comment: @Casey: if you are convinced that writing unit tests for getters & setters is the best investment of your unit testing skills and energy, go for it :-) Myself, working with legacy code (for most of my career... as is typical I believe), I have to admit that usually those tests are way down on my wish list of unit tests to write. If only those were my biggest worries...

Comment: @Péter well in my experience (short as it may be), when working with Legacy code, it's a whole other ball game. I've been workign with an ASP.NET/C# site for the past 6 months now, trying to fit unit testing into it without causing too much damage. The whole thing is horribly written and I have focused my unit testing on parts of it that really need to stay working and refactoring what and when I can around it.

Comment: @Casey sounds familiar - just the languages and acronyms vary :-) :-(

Comment: @Péter yeah. it's almost always the same concepts, just different syntax.

Comment: Testing getters and setters devalues your code coverage, and the getter and setters should either be being used by some behavior tested elsewhere (thus giving them coverage) or they should be removed since they are not tested as part of some behavior (and thus, should not be being used in production code).

The devaluing comes from not being able to find code not being used by any behavior and that includes unused getters and setters.

Comment: @Steven it does devalue the code coverage metric, but when management dictates you need 90% code coverage, you almost have to start testing the getters and setters.  I agree with Peter here, test the stuff that matters and makes sense.  I understand the theory of testing the getters/setters Brian mentions, but as devs we don't all have infinite time to spend on testing because theory says we should.  With the limited time we have, I test critical code first (code with high CCM, classes with High Ca).  Not all code is equal.

Answer (score 10):

If you have 100 fields in a class (with corresponding setters/getters) I suspect your object model is not decomposed correctly. 100+ fields sounds like an extraordinary number of fields for an object, and I would guess that it has several responsibilities that can be split across a number of more specialised objects.

Comment: While that is often the case, it may not necessarily be wrong to have that many fields. Imagine that this class exists to provide a Jaxb mapping to a very large XML file, for instance.

Answer (score 5):

You could perhaps use Apache Commons 'beanutils' to help automate this:

http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#getSimpleProperty%28java.lang.Object,java.lang.String%29

For instance there is a method `describe(Object bean)` which will return a map of all the readable attributes (ie, getters).

Then iterate that map and call:

```
setSimpleProperty(Object bean, String name, Object value)
```

and

```
public static Object getSimpleProperty(Object bean, String name)
```

And although I agree with the other poster than getters/setters are pretty trivial - I think it is still worth testing them - to eliminate typos, test property change listeners etc.

For example, this will dynamically extract the getters of a bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils;

public class MyTestBean implements Serializable {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
    private String x;
    private String y;
    private String z;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyTestBean bean=new MyTestBean();
    Set prop=PropertyUtils.describe(bean).keySet();
    for (Object o : prop) {
        System.out.println((String)o);
    }
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public int getC() {
        return c;
    }
    public void setC(int c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(String y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public String getZ() {
        return z;
    }
    public void setZ(String z) {
        this.z = z;
    }}
```

You will need to download both BeanUtils and CommonsLogging and both libraries' JARs to your project to run this code.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this library is the answer to your question: http://outsidemybox.github.com/testUtils/

it tests all the bean's initial values, the setters, the getters, hashCode(), equals() and toString(). All you have to do is define a map of default and non default property/value.

It can also test objects that are beans with additional non default constructors.

Comment: Just for future reference. Please refrain from Copy & Pasting answers and also from self-promoting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this in 2021 because this problem still persists.

Beans add up to the code base and have a very negative impact if your DevOps pipelines are imposing coverage restrictions on repos. There are two ways to overcome it.

1. Exclude the beans ( which I would say should not be done).
2. Write test cases for beans ( which is the most pathetic thing that we as a developer can do to waste our time :( ).

And in most cases, you will end up writing test cases for beans.

I have written this simple Utility/test case that uses reflection and can allow you to increase the Junit code coverage and save your time.

Bean under test: City

```
package com.test.beans;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author ameena
 *
 */
public class City {
    private int postOffices;
    private int jurdictaionAreas;
    private double areaInSqMeter;
    private long population;
    private List<City> neighbourCities;
    private boolean metro;

    public int getJurdictaionAreas() {
        return jurdictaionAreas;
    }

    public void setJurdictaionAreas(int jurdictaionAreas) {
        this.jurdictaionAreas = jurdictaionAreas;
    }

    public double getAreaInSqMeter() {
        return areaInSqMeter;
    }

    public void setAreaInSqMeter(double areaInSqMeter) {
        this.areaInSqMeter = areaInSqMeter;
    }

    public long getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(long population) {
        this.population = population;
    }

    public int getPostOffices() {
        return postOffices;
    }

    public void setPostOffices(int postOffices) {
        this.postOffices = postOffices;
    }

    public List<City> getNeighbourCities() {
        return neighbourCities;
    }

    public void setNeighbourCities(List<City> neighbourCities) {
        this.neighbourCities = neighbourCities;
    }

    public boolean isMetro() {
        return metro;
    }

    public void setMetro(boolean metro) {
        this.metro = metro;
    }
}
```

The class to automate the bean testing

```
package com.test.beans;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;

import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

/**
 * @author ameena
 *
 */
class BeanTest {

    public void invokeSetter(Object obj, String propertyName, Object variableValue)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor propDescriptor;
        try {
            propDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(propertyName, obj.getClass());
            Method setter = propDescriptor.getWriteMethod();
            try {
                setter.invoke(obj,variableValue);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                fail(e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public Object invokeGetter(Object obj, String variableName)
    {
        Object returnValue = null;
        try {
            PropertyDescriptor pd = new PropertyDescriptor(variableName, obj.getClass());
            Method getter = pd.getReadMethod();
            returnValue = getter.invoke(obj);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | IntrospectionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }
        return returnValue;
    }


    private <T extends Object> void validateGettersSetters(List<T> objects) {
        for (T t : objects) {
            Class<?> aClass = t.getClass();
            for (java.lang.reflect.Field field : aClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
                System.out.println(field);
                Class<?> c = field.getType();
                if (c == String.class) {
                    invokeSetter(t, field.getName(), "dummy");
                    assertEquals("dummy", (invokeGetter(t, field.getName())));
                } else if (c == Integer.class || c == int.class) {
                    invokeSetter(t, field.getName(), 1);
                    assertEquals(1, (invokeGetter(t, field.getName())));
                }else if (c == Double.class || c == double.class) {
                    invokeSetter(t, field.getName(), 1d);
                    assertEquals(1d, (invokeGetter(t, field.getName())));
                }else if (c == Long.class || c == long.class) {
                    invokeSetter(t, field.getName(), 1l);
                    assertEquals(1l, (invokeGetter(t, field.getName())));
                }else if (c == Boolean.class || c == boolean.class) {
                    invokeSetter(t, field.getName(), true);
                    assertEquals(true, (invokeGetter(t, field.getName())));
                }else if (c == List.class){
                    //Now based on your bean and filed name
                    switch(field.getName()) {
                    case "neighbourCities" :
                        invokeSetter(t, field.getName(), new ArrayList<City>());
                        assertNotNull(invokeGetter(t, field.getName()));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }

    @Test
    void testBean() {
        List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        objects.add(new City());
        validateGettersSetters(objects);

    }

}
```

Nothing fancy, but it saved me for writing test cases for 23 beans :)

Regards
Amit Meena