# Is there a way to automate junit bean property tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

Let's face it, writing bean property tests is possibly the worst use of time. But they need to be done.

For example. If testing a `String` property for `propName` a call such as the following:

```
testProperty(target, "propName", String.class);
testProperty(target, "propName", String.class, "expected initial");
```

Would validate that:

- `get` and `set` methods exist.
- If using expected value a test to `get` calls `assertEquals` for the given value.
- (`get`,`is`)/`set` methods behave as expected.

I could go an start writing these implementations, but I want to know if there is something available to facilitate this. Other optional attributes could be used to validate that `null` is allowed or use JSR-303 bean validation to validate the field.

Comment: Isn't it something exhaustive to test for getter/setter? Is it required?

Comment: IMHO, this type of testing should be avoided.  It will generate far more work than payoff, not to mention a ton of tests that need to be maintained.

Comment: I totally agree with both of you. Personally I never create the getter/setter and rely on NetBeans to create them. Whenever I modify them I delete prior getter/setter and regenerate them from the fields. But what about code-coverage?

Comment: `code-coverage` will be achieved if those getter/setter are called inside other test cases!

Comment: Isn't automating unit-tests kind of defeating their purpose?

Comment: @d33j, IMHO no. Every had a bug because the setter was setting the argument instead of the instance variable? This is something I've seen a lot of, where the method might be fine, yet the instance variable had a typo and no explicit `this.` in the setter. I'm sure there are more examples.

Comment: What about code coverage? The goal of development is not 100% coverage. Plus if it is not used in other tests, why keep it? One option - Project Lombok. Don't write the getters/setters. Nothing to to test.

Comment: Many business entity beans will be used only by service methods to populate these beans. These need testing to ensure that they are being returned from a mock service properly, however this is effectively just testing that the entity properties are working. Having an ability to test these without writing laborious and error prone tests is beneficial.

Comment: You can have a look at the following library, it may be what you are looking for:
http://outsidemybox.github.com/testUtils/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are quite a few existing code libraries/snippets that make this easier.  In doing a quick search I found a few that have potential:

- https://github.com/codebox/javabean-tester
- http://code.google.com/p/junit-javabean-runner/
- http://javabeantester.sourceforge.net/

I have seen someone take the first example I listed (nice and simple because it's just a single class) and modify it to better fit their needs.

Comment: Javabean-tester seems to be pretty poorly written and documented.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of [using reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/getters-setters.html) if you want to do it manually
or refer to this answer for commons:

[junit test method for getters & setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218177/junit-test-method-for-getters-setters)

Answer (score 0):

create another bean so it looks like your tested bean should. and then use apache-commons, festAssert, hamcrest or any other framework that can do the comparison using reflection. don't write it on your own, i'm certain it's already done

Answer (score 0):

**Update to the above javabean-tester**

There is a [active fork project](https://github.com/hazendaz/javabean-tester) to the above mentioned (but dead) codebox/javabean-tester which seems quite nice...