# Is there still no solution for ignoring setter/getter (other trivial methods) with the cobertura-maven-plugin?

Tags: testing, code-coverage, maven-plugin, cobertura

Did someone find a good solution to **ignore trivial methods**?
Using some automated testing like `Unitils` is not really an option, since the code-coverage should not go up if only getters/setters are tested!

Using **cobertrua-maven-plugin version 2.5.1**:
-) ignore for methods does not work `<ignore>com.company.*.set*</ignore>`
-) did anyone try to include a patch like http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3010530&group_id=130558&atid=720017 into the maven-plugin?
-) anyone uses a different (better?) test-plugin?

A general ignore for every get/set/is* method is also not really a good way, since these patterns can be used in other methods but simle getter/setters. Also it should be easy to guess trivial getters/setters/constructors.

I know about the question: [Ignore methods in class. cobertura maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225888/ignore-methods-in-class-cobertura-maven-plugin) but since it did not get any relevant answers, I thought I give it another shot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since Cobertura 2.0 there is a switch to exclude trivial methods:

> [[Cobertura Changelog]](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura#version-200)
>     **New** --ignoreTrivial switch that tells Cobertura to ignore the
>     following in the coverage report: Getter methods that simply 
>     read a class field; Setter methods that set a class field;
>     Constructors that only set class fields and call a super 
>     class constructor.

The cobertura-maven-plugin uses Cobertura 2.x since version 2.6 (see [release notes](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=11226&version=17376)). But i have not yet found a way to pass the switch to the maven plugin configuration.

---

Although there seems to be some confusion about the state of this feature (see this [Jira issue](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOBERTURA-171)), the flag does seem to work with the following configuration:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
<configuration>
  <instrumentation>
    <ignoreTrivial>true</ignoreTrivial>                 
  </instrumentation>
</configuration>
```

Comment: brilliant, I'll test and review as soon as I got 5mins

Comment: excellent, had to check the plugin code for the usage since I couldnt find it anywhere (thus, the include in the answer)

Comment: @AbGator it was already included (I checked the code) and it works (its included in our cycle) ..please check before you remove already tested and working information!

Comment: Sorry for the thread necro, but is there anything else I must do to make this work? I have this snippet in my <reporting><plugins><plugin> section, but the report is still complaining about simple getters and setters. Eclipse also didn't auto-complete the ignoreTrivial option. Do I need to import something else?

Comment: To modify the default instrumentation behavior, you have to override the plugin configuration in the build->plugins section of your pom (see  http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html section 2).

Answer (score 1):

The exclusion problem was fixed here:

```
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOBERTURA-52
```

and it's part of the latest release (2.5.2). It's available since 10 Sept. 2012:

```
http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.codehaus.mojo%22%20AND%20a%3A%22cobertura-maven-plugin%22
```